# Own component calls com_user login without it being invoked

Tags: authentication, components, joomla3.0

Synopsis - I have a component that redirects to com_user on form submit, but I do not call com_user anywhere ...

I am writing a component on Joomla 3.0  I have 1 controller, a couple of models and a few views.  In each of 2 views I have a form with a submit field which calls for a lookup field.  Based on that I return some data from a database lookup.  I use  JFactory::getSession() to detect the submitted data.
Everything works perfectly until I activate the "Login Form" module on the site.  When I do that my first view redirects to a login screen, whereas the second continues to work normally.  I have checked my code and cannot see any difference that would explain why one view behaves differently from another.

Session info on joomla debug does not help.

I am running Joomla 3.9.1 and PHP 7.0.32.  Any ideas would be welcomed.

or ideas on how to debug this would help.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to deconstruct my component.  I was able to recreate the problem by copying the view.html.php to another view so I was sure there was a problem with my code.  Turns out there was a problem with the closing  and  (interchanged and not always there depending on the circumstance)

I am guessing that those missing closure items caused a roll-over into the com_user login module.

## lessonLearnt